# Do we need to wrap all the screens with NativeBaseProvider in Native Base - React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have 3 screens here for example:

1. AuthScreen
2. HomeScreen
3. LoginScreen

---

**AuthScreen.js, HomeScreen.js, LoginScreen.js**
and have their respective content inside. And they are called by `<Stack.Navigator>` as shown [in the link here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container)

```
<NativeBaseProvider>
.
.
.
</NativeBaseProvider>
```

Is there a way I can just write the `NativeBaseProvider` once than have to do it on every screens?

Answer (score 1):

NativeBaseProvider is a component that makes the theme available throughout your app. It uses React's Context API. Add NativeBaseProvider to **the root of your app** and update App.js as follows:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
   <NativeBaseProvider>
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator>{/* ... */}</Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is how i've been using it in my app but this gives an error when testing with Jest. `useTheme must be used within NativeBaseConfigProvider`

Comment: ```TypeError: dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore is not a function.```